# Android Audio Manager in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, audio

I'm using this code below in BroadCast Receiver to get Audio Manager

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

But it's showing error & eclips says **AUDIO_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable**

Whats wrong here? How can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Comment: It should be `AudioManager audio = AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```